# Does an SPFx webpart run on Gulp or Node as web server?

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

Reading the SPFx documentation I find it difficult to understand which service/tool/framework handles requests as a web server. From documentation both Node and Gulp can be used as a web server during development.

## Abstracting tools

Node is a **runtime** which makes me think it's close to CLR on Windows machines. Gulp on the other hand is a **task runner** which makes me think it's an IIS website or its application pool. If I start `gulp serve` I can access my webpart in localhost. If I stop it, I can't.

Does Node or Gulp act as *webserver* during webpart development?

Comment: What comes down the pipe with ``@microsoft/sp-build-web``? (I haven't checked) Gulp runs on top of Node, so Node is always involved. There are multiple webserver/live reload solutions available.. or MS built one themselves because of SP specific requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither Gulp or Node act as the web server. The web server used for SPFx is **Connect**, see below.

These are (some of) the different moving parts in the SPFx workbench

- **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)**: is the *JavaScript runtime*, using Chrome V8 JavaScript engine (could be compared to .NET CLR)
- **[Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp)**: is a *build system* for Node.js (also known as a task runner)
- **[Gulp-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect)**: is a *Gulp task* using the Connect web server
- **[Connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)**: is a *http server* for Node.js

Answer (score 5):

SPFx uses a Gulp plugin called [Gulp connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect) to start the webserver hosting the Workbench.

You're right saying that Gulp is a task-runner. In a way you could compare it MSBuild in .NET development. Also your comparison of Node to CLR is correct in the context of SPFx.

Answer (score -1):

Node is the underlying server module for #spfx, so install node first and make sure its path is included in the system path.

I then created a ***windows*** command file (CMD) with the following contents an called it: installs.cmd

---

```
    call npm uninstall -g chalk
    call npm uninstall -g loadash
    call npm uninstall -g tar-fs
    call npm uninstall -g update-notifier
    call npm uninstall -g yeoman-generator
    call npm uninstall -g yosay
    call npm uninstall -g yo
    call npm uninstall -g gulp
    call npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

    call npm install -g chalk
    call npm install -g loadash
    call npm install -g tar-fs
    call npm install -g update-notifier
    call npm install -g yeoman-generator
    call npm install -g yosay
    call npm install -g yo
    call npm install -g gulp

    call npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

after this cmd runs, the you can type: yo @microsoft/generator-sharepoint 
to create your webpart....

Cheers,

Comment: This does not really answer the question asked at all